# The home page translation link is static and is not used to translate all pages

Tags: html, django

I have a problem I hope to solve it as I display in the navbar languages ​​used in the site and I want whenever you click on the language the page appears with the translation in all pages and not only the main page ,with the translation link changes with each page

http://127.0.0.1:8000/fr/

http://127.0.0.1:8000/fr/our-company

So add on the home page link.

How to fixed the link on the home page so that the translation is displayed for all pages and keep on the same page translated

Navbar home page in all pages

```
<ul class="navigation__dropdown-wrap--language">
    <li>
        <a data-culture="ar" data-lang="True" href="/">العربية</a>
    </li>
    <hr>
    <li>
        <a data-culture="en" data-lang="True" href="/en/" lang="en">English</a>
    </li>
    <hr>
    <li>
        <a data-culture="fr" data-lang="True" href="/fr/" lang="fr">français</a>
    </li>
    <hr>
</ul>
```

Comment: They are localhost links. You know that right?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into Django's [i18n](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/) package. It comes with full support for translations, timezones and locales. (Numbers and dateformats).

The package comes with support for [internationalized](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns) URLs.